# Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to test a POST method in a Nodejs/express application. I've connected to the firebase database. 
My question is mainly related to the error. What am I doing wrong  and how can I fix this please?

This is the error report:

> PS C:\Users\WorkoutApp_v1> node app.js
>   Server started on port: 3000
>
> **Error**: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'workouts.-Lqkqtcf6e2RED2F_1av.name'

This is the workout.js file with POST method.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const firebase = require('firebase');


router.get('/add', function(req,res,next) {
    res.render('workouts/add');
});

router.post('/add', function(req,res,next) {
     var workout = {
       name: req.body.name,
       discription: req.body.discription,
       set: req.body.set,
       repsTime: req.body.repsTime
     }
    // console.log(workout);
    // return;

    // const fbRef = firebase.database().ref();
    // var dbRef = fbRef.child('workouts');
    // dbRef.push().set(workout);


    // alternative implementation of the above 3-lines
    firebase.database().ref().child('workouts').push().set(workout);

    req.flash('success_msg', 'Workout saved');
    res.redirect('/workouts');
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the add.ejs file.

```
   <form method="post" action="/workouts/add">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Exercise</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Workout Name">
    <label>Description</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description">
    <label>Set</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sets" placeholder="Number of sets">
    <label>RepsTime</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="repsTime" placeholder="Number of repsTime">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
   <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/workouts">Close</a>
</form>
```

Comment: For node apps, I'll suggest that it's probably better to use the Firebase Admin SDK instead of the client libraries.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_different_environments

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, but how would this help me fixing the error I have?

Answer (score 2):

The value `undefined` can't be written in RTDB.

The value `undefined` is what you get when you access object properties that don't exist.

Your `req.body.name` is `undefined` because `req.body` doesn't have a `name` property.

What does your commented-out `console.log(workout)` print?

When you write code that might lead to writing `undefined` in RTDB, you should replace it with something else. In this scenario, you could use `req.body.name || ''`, to replace a missing `name` property with an empty string.

In general, using `||` can cause trouble, because values like `0` and `''` are equivalent to `false`, so they would be replaced by your default value.

A safer thing to do is `value === undefined ? defaultValue : value`.

Comment: @Stratusbas the console prints the last field - the numberOfReps field. { name: 'test' }, it was for testing. What I expect is to have the result of the form.

Comment: @user10728848 That is weird. There should be some values for the other properties too. Maybe your output is somehow formatted and you see only the last line? Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(workout))` instead.

Comment: Still it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: @user10728848 I would try `console.log`ging each `req.body` property separately. The problem isn't related to RTDB, it's the missing properties. Other than that, watch out with your spelling. You have `req.body.set` where it's `sets` in html, and `req.body.discription` where it's `description` in html. Finally, you're showing the success message and redirecting without first waiting for the `set` to succeed. You could declare the function as `async` and use `await` on the `set` call, or use `then` and `catch` on it. Good luck!